# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I got the error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions". It's happened when I try to a CoreData things. I've commented the line that related to CoreData but this error won't disappear. Could anyone know how to solve this ?

This is my ContentView Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    //@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    //@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])private var MyWalletCD : FetchedResults<MyWalletCD>
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    @EnvironmentObject private var mywalletList: myWalletList
    @State private var showAddWallet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                switch selectedIndex{
                case 0:
                    VStack{
                        NavigationView{
                            List{
                                ForEach(MyWalletCD , id:\.self ){ wallet in
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: WalletItemView(wallet:wallet),label: {
                                            HStack{
                                                Image(wallet.category ?? "")
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                Text(wallet.name ?? "untitled")
                                                    .foregroundColor(wallet.category == "Earning" ?.blue:.red)
                                                    .font(.title)
                                                wallet.category == "Earning" ?
                                                    Text("+" + String(wallet.total) ?? "")
                                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                                    .font(.title2):
                                                    Text("-" + String(wallet.total) ?? "")
                                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                                    .font(.title2)
                                            }
                                        })
                                }
                                .onDelete { indexSet in
                                    //MyWallet.wallets.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                                }
                        
                            }
                            .navigationBarTitle("ภาพรวม")
                            .navigationBarItems(
                                leading: Button(action: {
                                    showAddWallet.toggle()
                                }) {
                                    Text("Add")
                                }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showAddWallet) {
                                    AddWalletView(showAddWalletView: $showAddWallet)
                                        .environmentObject(self.mywalletList)
                                },
                                trailing: EditButton()
                            )
                        }
                        Text("Your cash balance is " + String(cashDisplay))
                    }
                case 1:
                    NavigationView{
                        NavigationLink(destination: summaryView()){
                            Text("คลิ๊กที่นี่เพื่อดูกราฟ")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .navigationTitle("สรุป")
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    Text("No")
                }
            }
            
            HStack{
                Button(action: {selectedIndex = 0}, label: {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Image("ภาพรวม")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        Text("ภาพรวม")
                            .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == 0 ? Color(.black) : .init(white: 0.8))
                    }
                    Spacer()
                })
                Button(action: {selectedIndex = 1}, label: {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Image("Report")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == 1 ? Color(.black) : .init(white: 0.8))
                        Text("สรุป")
                            .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == 1 ? Color(.black) : .init(white: 0.8))
                    }
                    Spacer()

                })
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}


struct WalletItemView: View {
    var wallet: MyWalletCD
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Image(wallet.category ?? "")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Text(wallet.name ?? "")
            Text(" : ")
            Text(String(wallet.total))
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(myWalletList())
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be a problem: `ForEach(MyWalletCD , id:\.self )`?

Comment: I've changed it to  `ForEach(mywalletList.wallets)` it's work. Like I said this problem happen when I try to changed from List to CoreData. Did you know why this happen ?

Comment: Sometimes when the compiler struggles to work out types because of some typo in code. It gives this error when the compiler can't work it out. You can also, as it says, split up the code. This usually shows you the real error message if you split it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the line:

```
ForEach(MyWalletCD, id: \.self) { wallet in
```

You need to instead pass in either a range or a set of data into the `ForEach`. That's why you fixed it with:

```
ForEach(mywalletList.wallets) { wallet in
```

Each element, `wallet`, comes from the `wallets` array.

Additional notes: The error you received sometimes occurs when the compiler struggles to work out types because of some typo/mistake in your code. It gives this error when the compiler can't work it out. You can also, as it says, split up the code. This usually shows you the real error message if you split it up.